# Split in javascript based on regex

Tags: javascript, regex, split

**Regex needed that will split string based on following criteria**

I need to split string based on regex in javascript. The format of the string is as follows 'publication_or_portfolio_links.0.link'

I need to split based on '.index.' (note dot before and after the inex) i.e. the result should be 'publication_or_portfolio_links' and 'link' i.e. '.0.' has been removed.

I would be thankful if some help me.

Comment: The separator argument for [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) can be a regular expression.

Comment: What problem are you having? The `split()` method allows the delimiter to be a regexp, so just write a regexp that matches `.<number>.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `\.\d+\.`

Demo:

```js
const str = 'publication_or_portfolio_links.0.link';

const res = str.split(/\.\d+\./gm)

console.log(res)
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/) explanation:

[image]